# preg_replace width in script tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Using preg_replace for script tag.

```
<script src="/player.js?video=204442&width=300&height=198&mproce=true&primaryColor=0xFF9900&showFeed=0&autoplay=0&browser=0&partnerid=130101" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I would like to replace width and height with new values. Now I have a solution with substr and strpos, but perhaps preg_replace would be a nicer solution.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
$str = '<script src="/player.js?video=204442&width=300&height=198&mproce=true&primaryColor=0xFF9900&showFeed=0&autoplay=0&browser=0&partnerid=130101" type="text/javascript"></script>';

$str = preg_replace('/width=\d+/i', 'width=999', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/height=\d+/i', 'height=999', $str);

print_r( $str );
```